# strftime %Z behaves differently on Time and DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
>> Time.now.strftime("%Z")
=> "CST"
>> DateTime.now.strftime("%Z")
=> "+08:00"
>> DateTime.new(2017, 2, 1, 17, 30, 0, "PST").strftime("%Z")
=> "-08:00"
```

So I want to print out the timezone name so I reached to `strftime`. However it behaves differently if I give a DateTime to it. Why is this the case? Does that mean I can't use DateTime.new to initialize an arbitrary time of a specific timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the time zone of a `DateTime` with `in_time_zone`:

```
DateTime.now.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%Z")
```

`Time` will automatically include a time zone if specified.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue. This appears to be the cause:

- `Time` knows its time zone (and we can derive the offset from that)
- `DateTime` only knows its offset from UTC (which might be more than
  one time zone, because of inconsistent observance of Daylight Savings Time)

For example, right now both Phoenix, Arizona and San Francisco, CA are the same offset from UTC (-0700), but different time zones (MST, and PDT, respectively).